# Jpeg module in Python (on Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: python, image, jpeg, raspbian

I tried to compress captured image (saved into file) by using jpeg module in Python 2.7.9. I know it's deprecated since version 2.6 and not available in Python 3.x and now I also know that it was (just?) for IRIX. I would just like to know whether there is some comparable module available for Python? Before I learned about that IRIX module I wrote a program using it (in "zlib fashion"). Here's a part of the program so that you'll see what comparable module I have in mind:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys, time
import jpeg


unencoded = open('image_Y.data','rb').read()
print ('Size of unencoded Y:',sys.getsizeof(unencoded))

start = time.time()

jpeg.setoption('quality', 70)
comprim = open('image_Y_comprim_jpeg.data','wb')
comprim.write(jpeg.compress(unencoded, 100, 100, 1))
t_compress = time.time() - start


comprim = open('image_Y_comprim_jpeg.data','rb').read()
decomprim = jpeg.decompress(comprim)
decompr = open('image_Y_decomprim_jpeg.data','wb')
decompr.write(decomprim) 

t_decompress = time.time() - start
t_all = t_compress + t_decompress

CR = sys.getsizeof(unencoded)/sys.getsizeof(comprim)
```

The emphasis is on being able to compress the unencoded image (mine has only luma component), like the one in 'image_Y.data', and to choose the quality of compression, and then to decompress the image. Thank you for suggestions.